Cup length lower bound of lusternik-schnirelmann category?
Intuitively it seems to me that the cup length of a topological space is smaller than or equal to the lusternik-schnirelmann category of it, but is it strictly smaller? And if so what is the proof outline of it? My immediate guess is that you can prove it using relative cup product.
Here LS of a space is the minimum number of contractible open sets to cover it. As for the cup length it is the maximal n such that $x_1⌣x_2....⌣x_n \neq 0$ where $x_i∈H^k(X),k≥1$

Please tell us more about your thoughts on these questions.

You should also provide your definition of the LS category, because this is not entirely uniform throughout the literature.

...and of cup length, for that matter.

@Thorgott Here LS of a space is the minimum number of contractible open sets to cover it. As for the cup length it is the maximal n such that $x_1 \smile x_2.... \smile x_n \neq 0$ where $x_i \in H^k(X), k \geq 1$

@Categoryofhumans Please edit your question with that info. Also you probably want to assume that at least the cup length is finite for this.

It can happen that that both Lusternik-Schnirelmann and cup length are countably infinite, for instance for $\mathbb{C}\mathrm{P}^\infty$.
If the cup length is finite, however, then it is strictly smaller than the Lusternik-Schnirelmann category, independent of the choice of coefficient ring $R$. To see this, let $X$ be a space of finite Lusternik-Schnirelmann category $n \in \mathbb{N}_+$ and let $U_1, \ldots, U_n$ be a cover of $X$ by contractible opens. Note that $\tilde{H}^*(X; R) \cong H^*(X, U_i; R)$ via the inclusion map, so by naturality of the cup product we obtain a commutative square

for any choice of  $k_1, \ldots, k_n > 0$, but the group at the bottom right is $H^{k_1 + \ldots + k_n}(X, X; R) = 0$ whence all products of length $n$ (in strictly positive degrees) are trivial and the cup length of $X$ is at most $n - 1$.

I'm slightly confused by your first sentence. The cup length is necessarily finite, as the argument shows.

@Thorgott It covers the case that both are infinite (with a suitably lax interpretation of "maximum"), which I then tacitly drop and slide into the only interesting case of both finite. I'll clarify.

Thank you for this excellent proof. In Hatcher he uses direct product of groups instead of tensor for the cup-map (p. 209). Does it make a difference or am I missing some subtlety?

@Categoryofhumans By the universal property of the tensor product, it's "the same:" You can either view the cup product as an $R$-multilinear map from the cartesian product or as an $R$-linear map from the tensor product.
